# RegionFunction doesn't work in ListContourPlot if also using ScalingFunctions

Tags: plotting, regions, options, logarithmic-scale

I am making a contour plot out of a list of values of the form `{{x1,y1,f1},{x2,y2,f2},…}` I want to plot this on a log log scale so I specify `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}` but I also want to only plot the data over a particular region of the range. Such as above the line specified by: `RegionFunction -> (#2 > -# + 1 &)` but these won't work together.

So here is a basic example that highlights the problem:

```
list = Flatten[Table[{i, j, i^2 - j^2}, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}, {j, 0, 1, 0.01}], 1];
ListContourPlot[list, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]
ListContourPlot[list, RegionFunction -> (#2 > -# + 1 &)]
ListContourPlot[list, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
      RegionFunction -> (#2 > -# + 1 &)]
```

The first two work but when I try to combine `RegionFunction` and `ScalingFunctions` it doesn't work.

Thoughts on a workaround?
Thanks!

Comment: Please, give at least some example for `list` to test with.

Comment: I just did. Good point.

Comment: does `RegionFunction -> (Exp[#2]+Exp[#]>1 &)` give the desired region or do you want the triangle as in the second plot?

Comment: I want the last line of code to work. So just the upper triangular region and scaled log log axes.

Comment: It really doesn't matter what region I am referring to though. The point is `RegionFunction`  and `ScalingFunctions` don't work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per kglr's comment, the following produces

```
g = ListContourPlot[list, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 RegionFunction -> (Exp[#2] + Exp[#1] > 1 &)
 ]
```

[image]

so `ScalingFunctions` and `RegionFunction` do work together. Indeed, this contour plot should correspond to the logarithmized version of this

```
ListContourPlot[list, 
 RegionFunction -> (#2 + #1 > 1 &)
 ]
```

In fact, the logarithmically scaled axes lie to you as can be seen by plotting the contour plot `g` from above together with the unit disk:

```
Show[
 Graphics[Disk[]],
 g
 ]
```

[image]

Hence your code

```
ListContourPlot[list, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#2 > -#1 + 1 &)]
```

because *there are no points in `list` that, after logarithmical rescaling fullfil the condition of `RegionFunction`.*

Comment: Thanks this makes sense now.

Comment: Well the sum of to exponentials is always positive, right? With, e.g., `RegionFunction -> (Exp[#2] + Exp[-45*(#1/4)^(-0.4229)] > 20 &)`, you will see a difference.

Comment: I deleted my comment above about doing this for above a power law region because I figured it out. For the region above y=45(x/4)^(-0.4229) with `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}`  I actually wanted `RegionFunction -> (Exp[#2] - 45*(Exp[#]/4)^(-0.4299)] > 0 &)` Very strange.....but I figured it out. Like why do you leave everything the same except the rescaled variables? Also why isn't it 10^(#2) instead of Exp[#2] when the axes are base 10 scaled it seems? Either way I made it work. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: Good point. But standard Log-Scaling is with respect to `Log`. Only the tick marks are to base 10. You can also use `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "Log10"}`. If you prefer a `Log10`-`Log10` plot.

Comment: Oh, ok well that part makes sense then at least. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.